What are the most recent efforts to develop sarcopenia drugs to combat muscle loss due to semaglutide use?
There are lot of news that the use of semaglutides reduces the muscle mass as well and this article https://www.uclahealth.org/news/article/rapid-weight-loss-can-lead-loss-muscle-mass is the only one that I have managed to find, that confirms, that the drug companies are aware of this and that they are actively seeking improved drugs to tackle this:

To combat this, drug manufacturers are racing to develop medications
to address the problem. Some are planning clinical trials of drugs
that will boost muscle metabolism and metabolic function. Others are
exploring medications that would block the signaling pathways that
lead to muscle loss. In the meantime, people at risk of sarcopenia due
to rapid weight loss are advised to tackle the problem on two fronts:
diet and exercise. This includes eating enough calories to maintain
good health and making sure to include adequate protein in the diet.
When it comes to exercise, weight-bearing exercises that build muscle
are important.

My question is - what new initiatives, additions to pipelines have been made in this race? I am searching Google for the signs of this race but I have not find anything extraordinary beyond the usual process of sarcopenia drug development.
Added: The central idea of the Nature Biotech article is:

For the longest time, people have talked about skeletal muscle
function as being undruggable, but in the last ten years or so, that
has changed

What an exciting times we are making now!

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-024-02176-5 is recent review no paywalled Nature journal.

https://www.freethink.com/health/muscle-loss-glp-1-agonists is nice, free-access list of some ongoing efforts.

The problem is most pharmaceutical companies don't reveal their drug discovery efforts until they're well along.

Does it strike anyone that fighting drug side effects with yet another drug can be problematic both medically and ethically?

Regarding your edit: Fixed it for you, but please don't direct us to something in comments. Comments are ephemeral, they can be deleted for any reason at any time. Links need to be in the question, not in comments.
